# I want to switch between windows with customtkinter in Python. I want it to close a window and open a new window when the button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I researched everywhere but couldn't find any results. Isn't there such a feature in the library? Please help me! I tried closing the window and opening a new one at the same time, but it didn't work.

```
class UI(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def exit():
        UI.exit() #didn't work :(
```

Comment: "didn't work" isn't a very useful description. Please create a [mcve]. I see no reason why you can't do what you want, tkinter absolutely supports destroying old windows and creating new windows.

Comment: Your code snippet is not a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).